# When can a metaphor become a double entendre

Tags: figures-of-speech

I've been engaged in debate for some days now, about a discussion in a panel of a Captain America comic book.

In the comic book, Bucky, his sidekick, says that "you have been running a mile a minute since you got the super soldier serum".

Given that Captain America can (occasionally) run that fast, some people are of the opinion it is a double entendre.

I am of the opinion that it is purely a metaphor, given that the context doesn't show him running and seems to be purely referring to how hard he has been pushing himself, regardless of what speed he can run at.

Here is a [link](http://static.comicvine.com/uploads/scale_super/10/101999/3210678-cap-moot_001_014.jpg) to the scan.

Is there a way to tell if "running a mile a minute" in the example above is a metaphor, or a double entendre?

If it is a double entendre, what makes it so as opposed to being just a metaphor?

Comment: "some people are of the opinion it is a double entendre." What would be the hidden meaning? What other interpretation can *...running a mile a minute...* have? OR is it the **"super soldier serum"** which people believe has the double entendre?! :)

Comment: @Mari-louA They are trying to use that panel as proof to argue that Captain American can run at 60 mph. They are saying that it is a double entendre because the second meaning is that he can literally run at that speed.

Comment: In the LITERAL sense of the word.http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/literal. It's not a double entendre. Tell your friends they are wrong. :)

Comment: "When correctly viewed, **everything** is lewd. I could tell you things about Peter Pan -- and the Wizard of Oz? **There's** a dirty old man!" -- [Tom Lehrer, "Smut"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iaHDBL7dVgs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The literal meaning of running a mile a minute seems irrelevant to the action portrayed in the panel; instead the metaphorical meaning suggested in the question (that Captain America has been working to the point of exhaustion) is quite plausible and is reinforced by several pictures in the panel.  In addition there is no obvious and plausible meaning for “running a mile a minute” that is risqué, bawdy, or ironic.

In short, it appears that  “running a mile a minute” has been used metaphorically, and that whoever suggested it was a [double entendre](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/double_entendre#Noun) apparently doesn't know what one  is: “A phrase that has two meanings, especially where one is innocent and literal, the other risqué, bawdy, or ironic; an innuendo”.

Comment: As you rightly pointed out, the question is a NARQ.

Comment: @Kris, I'm sorry, how is my question not a real question?

Comment: @Muyjingo jwpat starts with 'The literal meaning of running a mile a minute seems irrelevant to the action portrayed in the panel' -- so the question is based on a misinterpretation/ misunderstanding. Not to speak of "whoever suggested it was a double entendre apparently doesn't know what one is" -- You see?